# base64 image not displaying in html <img>

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to display my base64 image that I converted in my php file. However the image in my html appears as the generic image placeholder for when an image is not available or existent.
In case anyone is wondering I am trying to display images that belong to a specific web page form. However I have many forms and when I click on one of them I want to be able to see the images associated.

I have gotten this far:
my PHP file looks like this:

```
$imageDate = date_format($currentdate, 'YmdHis');
$path = 'C:/Temp/MgrReportUploads';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$files = glob($path.
    '/'.$imageDate.
    '_*');

if (!empty($files)) {
    foreach($files as $image) {

        $vals['encodedImages'] = 'data:image/'.$type.
        ';base64,'.base64_encode($image);

    }
}
```

echo json_encode ( $vals);
response looks like this on the Network Tab
returnedImages: {,…}

```
images: "data:image/jpg;base64,QzovVGVtcC9NZ3JSZXBvcnRVcGxvYWRzLzIwMTkxMTA4MTM0MzM5X2plZGkxLmpwZw=="
```

js File
// callback variables on the form and Images

```
onSuccess: function(data) {

    var imgList = document.querySelector('#imageLst'); //div
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", data.encodedImages);
    imgList.append(img);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `base64_encode($image)` to `base64_encode(file_get_contents($image))`

`glob` returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

You have to pass file content not file path to `base64_encode`

Comment: I'll try it, what's the difference?

Comment: You should pass the file content to `base64_encode`, not the file path.

Comment: ahhhh that worked! That makes total sense. One more question, if there are more than one image that match the phrase I listed above they should be able to be passed in correct?

Comment: Yes. I've to filter out the directory.

Comment: Even if they are all in the same folder?